# Как передать и принять форму на сервер Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Как отправить заполненную форму на сервер Node.js?
Сервер находится на heroku. С сайта будет отправляться сообщение, в котором будет имя, фамилия, эл.почта и комментарии отправителя. Я понял, что надо отправлять из браузера методом `method= "post"`, но не знаю, что писать в `action`.

Какой есть самый простой вариант решения? Сервер создан с Express.

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();


app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index');
});

app.use('/form_handler', bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/form_handler', function(req, res, next){
    console.dir(req.body);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

вот мой сервер,что не так я прописал? 503 ошибка '/form_handler'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле все невероятно просто. На клиентской стороне вам нужно определить HTML форму:

```
<!-- Обратите внимание на атрибут action -->
<form action="/form_handler" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <!-- Другие поля добавляются аналогично -->
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

На серверной стороне вам нужно определить обработчик формы. Для того, чтобы правильно разобрать тело запроса существует множество модулей. Самый простой из них [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). Код с его использованием выглядит так:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Обратите внимание на используемый путь. Именно он задается в атрибуте action формы
app.use('/form_handler', bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// Обратите внимание на используемый путь. Именно он задается в атрибуте action формы
app.post('/form_handler', function(req, res, next) {
    // Объект req.body содержит данные из переданной формы
    console.dir(req.body);
});
```

Comment: что такое "/form_handler" в консоли в разделе network (chrome) 503 ошибка

Comment: `/form_handler` это путь, к которому вы подвязываете обработчик формы

Comment: что туда надо прописать?

Comment: @RomanPawliw, путь, к которому вы подвязываете обработчик формы. У вас ведь приложение на express, а раз так, то вы сами определяете как обрабатывать запросы к конкретным маршрутам. В моем примере express приложение обрабатывает данные формы по адресу `/form_handler` и именно это значение и указано в атрибуте `action`. В вашем коде обработчик может быть подвязан к другому пути. Тем не менее пути должны быть согласованы

Comment: как узнать какой путь у моего обработчика?

Comment: @RomanPawliw вы же сами его определяете! Еще раз: значение атрибута `action` должно быть таким же как и первый аргумент в `app.use` и `app.post` в моем примере кода.

Comment: все сработало , спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @RomanPawliw, если я полностью ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте ответ как "принятый" (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: отметил.......)

Answer (score 0):

В [атрибуте `action`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/action) указывается URL, на который отправляется форма. Пример:

```
<form method="POST" action="/page">
  <p>...</p>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```